# How can i block loading of images with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, blocking

I want to block all images on a webpage. There will be grey boxes instead of images.

Like *lazy load* , **but** images will **not** load while scrolling.

How can i do this with jquery ? Are there any function for this?

Comment: Does it really depend on loading? Or do you want to "not display" them? The loading of new images is done with AJAX if you are on a certain position. So it is not "not loading", but "do load" at the right moment I think.

Comment: @Marnix, images must be blocked while page is loading. So, i can increase my webpages speed (for example) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('img').attr('src', 'img_with_square_border.jpg');
```

This should work perfectly.

...Unless, of course, you wanted to load the images back when the user gets to them.

**EDIT TO ACCOMMODATE CLICKING**

```
$('img').each(function () { this.setAttribute('real-src', this.src); })
        .attr('src', 'whatever.jpg')
        .click(function () { this.src = this.getAttribute('real-src'); });
```

Comment: but all images have different sizes . And later , how can i find these images real address for load images.

Comment: @Eray If the `img_with_square_border` is just a solid color, then distorting it to all different sizes should be okay, right? Under what circumstances will you be loading the images back - when the user scrolls to them, when certain elements are clicked, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that replaces images with a gray box, and retains a reference to the original image using `.data()`.

**Example::** http://jsfiddle.net/GTQTC/2/ *(will revert back after 3 seconds)*

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    var div = $('<div>', {
        className: 'replacement',
        width: $th.width(),
        height: $th.height(),
        display: $th.css('display'),
        css:{'backgroundColor':'#DDD'}
    })
        .data('originalImage',this);
    $th.replaceWith(div);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.replacement').replaceWith(function() {
        return $(this).data('originalImage');
    });
}, 3000);
```